# Why do I get : ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional or an integer when I use : random.choice(x.remove())?

Tags: python

I get the following error when I run this code:
'''

```
  zo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  cl={}
  for k in range(1, 10):
     ori = np.random.choice(zo)
     des = np.random.choice(zo.remove(ori))
     cl[k] = (ori,des)
```

----> 7     des = np.random.choice(zo.remove(ori))

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional or an integer

Comment: You are calling `np.random.choice(zo.remove(ori))` - but the result of `zo.remove(ori)` is `None`, which is not 1-dimensional nor an integer

Answer (score 0):

```
zo = np.array(zo) 
cl={} 
for k in range(1, 10): 
   ori = np.random.choice(zo)
   indices = np.where(zo==ori)
   zo = np.delete(zo, indices)
   des = np.random.choice(zo) 
   cl[k] = (ori,des)
```

You missed quite a few things in your code
`np.random.choice(zo)` --> `zo` should be 1D array

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end:

```
zo.append(ori)
```

and it works!

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `np.random.choice(zo.remove(ori))` - but the result of `zo.remove(ori)` is `None`, which is not 1-dimensional nor an integer

Perhaps you were after:

```
import numpy as np

zo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
cl = {}
for k in range(1, 10):
    ori = np.random.choice(zo)
    zo.remove(ori)
    des = np.random.choice(zo)
    cl[k] = (ori, des)

print(cl)
```

Example result:

```
{1: (8, 2), 2: (10, 6), 3: (6, 5), 4: (5, 1), 5: (7, 1), 6: (9, 2), 7: (2, 3), 8: (1, 4), 9: (3, 4)}
```

Comment: But if I try to get a dict  both ori and des, and a k in range of f.x. 50 , I get the error:

Comment: ValueError: 'a' cannot be empty unless no samples are taken

Comment: '''     zo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
       cl = {}
       clo={}
       cld = {}
       for k in range(1, 50):
              ori = np.random.choice(zo, replace= True)
              clo[k] = (ori)
              zo.remove(ori)
              des = np.random.choice(zo, replace= True)
              cld[k] = (des)
              cl[k] = (ori, des)


print(cl)
print(clo)
print(cld)